# What's a bulletproof way to deploy an internal Perl application with CPAN dependencies?

Tags: perl, deployment, dependency-management

First, the background information:

- All servers are under our control
- All Perls are exactly the same (latest Strawberry Perl)
- All target machines have similar OS configurations (Windows Server 20XX)
- None of the target machines are connected to the internet
- Legacy CGI web application running under IIS
- Small team of developers developing on their own machines
- Continuous integration environment

My initial thought was to use [Carton](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carton), but given that we have full control over the entire process, this might be overkill. We could run a `carton bundle` on the CI server and then a `carton install --cached --deployment` on each of the target servers. It seems like that would work, but then we'd have to modify every single file to `use lib` (or set a `PERL5LIB` environment variable, but that kind of defeats the purpose of using Carton in the first place).

I'm not opposed to modifying the system Perl, because, like I said, these are our servers, and we have full control over them. I wouldn't be opposed to some other method of bundling installed modules with the application, either. Even the XS modules wouldn't cause problems because the architectures and Perls are all the same. I just want to be able to use modules from CPAN and have it all work at deploy time, every single time.

What am I missing?

Comment: "I wouldn't be opposed to some other method of bundling installed modules with the application" Like [`pp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp)?

Comment: We do use `PAR::Packer` for some standalone scripts, but the application in question is actually a _web_ (intranet) application, with hundreds of individual `.pl` files. I'll edit the original question to make that more clear.

Comment: What about creating a distribution for your source and getting the dependencies from a [local CPAN mirror](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CPAN-Mini/bin/minicpan)?

Comment: I don’t think Carton is overkill FWIW. Sounds like a good solution and a nice way to ensure versioning during deployment while allowing devs to easily test changes in development environments.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot When you say 'distribution', do you mean a CPAN-like package, or something else?

Comment: @MattJacob A distribution like you find on CPAN, yes. In other words, a tarball containing your source files and a `Makefile.PL`, `Build.PL`, or similar. Distributions intended for upload to CPAN usually include various and sundry other files (e.g. `LICENSE`), but you probably don't need them in this case. Tools like [`Dist::Zilla`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla) can help you create a distribution. Once you have a distribution, copy it over to the target host, untar it, and run something like `perl Makefile.PL`, which will install your source along with any dependencies.

Comment: What about [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib)? Same downsides as Carton (have to add `use lib` to everything), with an additional downside of its own (have to put a bunch of installed modules under version control). But---it's simple and it's predictable.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot In that scenario, I'd also have to ship a minicpan with the release, right? (Isolated network w/no internet connection on target machines.)

Comment: @MattJacob You should be able to set up a single local mirror somewhere on your network and configure `cpan` on all your target hosts to point to it (assuming they're on a network at all).

Answer (score 2):

I have a totally automated installation of IIS, Strawberry Perl, CPAN modules + application. This is the cpan part of it.

It writes all cpan commands to a text file, then calls cpan with this as parameter.

Run it in two modes, either train the master installation with latest downloads (or version-ed downloads), or force a local (no-network) installation using a copy of the master.

Hopefully it may be of some help

```
set cpan_notest=
@IF '%skip_cpan_test%' NEQ '' GOTO SKIPPED_SKIP_CPAN_TEST
    set cpan_notest=
:SKIPPED_SKIP_CPAN_TEST

@IF '%skip_cpan%' NEQ '' GOTO SKIPPED_CPAN
    @echo EasyRisk install: CPAN starting

    @REM some modules do ask questions about things (XML::Twig)
    @set PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT=1

    @REM for CPAN to work, Perl must be in the path
    @REM but local environment (for this .cmd) is not updated when perl is installed
    @REM Need to fetch from registry and set it from a CALL'ed .cmd-file 
    @REM (looks like only way to do it, sorry)
    @echo.
    @echo Updating local path with ref to perl bin
    @echo Local path was:  %PATH%
    @"%local-perl-path-bin%\Perl.exe" Utils\update_path.pl > Utils\update_path.cmd
    @REM cpan is a batch-file, so use CALL. Otherwise it will end this script as well
    @call Utils\update_path.cmd > NUL
    @del Utils\update_path.cmd
    @echo.
    @echo Local path now:  %PATH%
    @echo.


    @set cpan-prefix=
    @set cpan-postfix=

    @REM some issues with testing  formbuilder on Perl 5.17+(modules works fine)
    @REM do not print errors, as the tests are wrong, but module considered ok. 
    @REM (the 2>&1 means send std error to std out, which is already grounded to NUL)
    @REM -f not strong enough, need to use 'force' from command-line (piped)

    @echo.
    @REM @echo Installing Perl Modules (CPAN), result is stored in log\cpan_result.txt

    @REM Clear the install file, then fill it with list of needed modules
    @REM make sure we install only from local modules
    @echo.  >  cpan_cmd.txt
    @REM Set that we only want to use local cpan, and not get stuff from internet
    @echo o conf commit >>  cpan_cmd.txt

    @REM if we are not training the local cpan-directory, then force to use the local copy
    @REM If any modules added, then the minicpan must also be updated (trained)
    @REM after training, copy C:\strawberry\cpan\sources to <installkit>\Utils\minicpan
    @IF '%train_cpan%' NEQ '' GOTO SKIPPED_CPAN_TRAIN_1

    @echo Transfering local copy of cpan perl modules (minicpan)
        @xcopy  /s /q /y /i Utils\minicpan "%local-perl-path%\minicpan"

        @echo o conf auto_commit 0 >>  cpan_cmd.txt

        @echo o conf connect_to_internet_ok '' >>  cpan_cmd.txt
        @REM dont init, just use local @echo o conf init urllist >>  cpan_cmd.txt
        @REM Remove default cpan repositories
        @echo o conf urllist shift >>  cpan_cmd.txt
        @echo o conf urllist shift >>  cpan_cmd.txt
        @echo o conf urllist shift >>  cpan_cmd.txt

        @REM add our local first, and only
        @echo o conf urllist %local-minicpan-file% >>  cpan_cmd.txt
        @rem view it in the log (good for debug)
        @echo o conf urllist >>  cpan_cmd.txt


    :SKIPPED_CPAN_TRAIN_1

    @echo Building Cpan-install list

    @REM Version specific (example only)
    @REM echo install SAMV/Set-Object-1.28.tar.gz
    @REM version independent
    @REM echo install Set::Object


    @echo %cpan_notest%  install Test::More Devel::CheckOS Pod::Coverage Class::ISA   Test::Simple Devel::Symdump Test::Pod::Coverage Pod::Coverage Test::Pod  Test::Compile YAML Data::Inherited Data::Comparable Data::Compare Devel::CheckOS Text::Template HTML::Template CGI::FastTemplate FreezeThaw   %cpan-postfix% >>  cpan_cmd.txt

    @REM Error in tests, (module works fine), but tests fails in 5.18, so use the force
    @echo force install CGI::Session CGI::Session::Driver::odbc CGI::FormBuilder %cpan-postfix% >>  cpan_cmd.txt




    @REM reset the config (as we did modify the list of urls)
    @echo o conf defaults >>  cpan_cmd.txt
    @echo exit >>  cpan_cmd.txt

    @REM now run the file with cpan, and remove it afterwards 
    @REM 2>&1 means redirect std err to std out (which goes to log\cpan_result.log)

    @echo Installing CPAN modules (from minicpan), this may take a while
    @echo See progress in "%setup_dir%\log\cpan_result.log"
    @REM temporary cd to the Perl-bin folder to be sure 
    @REM cpan and Perl are run from same Perl version 
    @cd /D "%local-perl-path-bin%"
    @set cpan-start=%TIME%
    @type "%setup_dir%\cpan_cmd.txt" | cpan > "%setup_dir%\log\cpan_result.log" 2>&1
    @set cpan-end=%TIME%
    @cd /D %setup_dir%

    @REM @del cpan_cmd.txt
    @echo 'EasyRisk install: Cpan done'
    @IF '%do_pause%' NEQ '' pause 
:SKIPPED_CPAN
```